# Select features by joining table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, excel

I have *.shp* layer with field `"FIELD_1"` in the attribute table (5000 records). I have also Excel file with field `"FIELD_2"` in the attribute table (1600 records).

I want to select in *.shp* all 1600 records from Excel file (`"FIELD_1"` and `"FIELD_2"` have corresponding attributes). What tool should I use?

Comment: Excel is a spreadsheet application, not a database. If the data is table-like enough to read as a table, then you can do so. Otherwise you would have to reformat it, then use the result. GIS SE is *problem-solving* site, so you need to tell us what tool you used, and what resulted before we could recommend a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an expression.

I have a point layer called `random` with the field `FIELD_1`.

I have dragged and dropped an excel table called `abcd` with a field named `Field1`.

I want to select all points whose `FIELD_1` value is in the Excel table `Field1` column.

`array_agg` is creating an array of all values in the `Field1` field of the layer `abcd`, and `array_contains` is selecting all rows in the point layer whose `FIELD_1` value is in the aggregated array:

```
array_contains( array:=
aggregate( layer:='abcd', aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="Field1"), value:="FIELD_1")
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Many thanks it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

It is a one line command with ogrinfo or ogr2ogr.

Take a shapefile that has an id field "shp_id"

[image]

Then take an Excel table that has on id field "excel_id"

[image]

Excel_ids 10, 11, and 12 appear also in the shp_id of the shapefile.

Then have a look at the JOIN in the GDAL SQLite SQL dialect documentation https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html.

Before writing the command we must know what table names GDAL finds from the shapefile and the Excel spreadsheet file. Use ogrinfo for the check.

```
ogrinfo jointest.shp
INFO: Open of `jointest.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: jointest (Point)

ogrinfo jointest.xlsx
INFO: Open of `jointest.xlsx'
      using driver `XLSX' successful.
1: table1 (None)
```

The table names are "jointest" and "table1".

```
ogrinfo jointest.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select shape.*,excel.* from
 jointest shape LEFT JOIN 'jointest.xlsx'.table1 excel
 ON shape.shp_id=excel.excel_id where excel.excel_id is not null"
    INFO: Open of `jointest.shp'
          using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
    
    Layer name: SELECT
    Geometry: Point
    Feature Count: 3
    Extent: (21.701551, 64.282740) - (21.934438, 64.479450)
    Layer SRS WKT:
    (unknown)
    Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
    shp_id: Integer (0.0)
    excel_id: Integer (0.0)
    attr: String (0.0)
    OGRFeature(SELECT):0
      shp_id (Integer) = 10
      excel_id (Integer) = 10
      attr (String) = foo
      POINT (21.7015510367855 64.4794502413075)
    
    OGRFeature(SELECT):1
      shp_id (Integer) = 11
      excel_id (Integer) = 11
      attr (String) = bar
      POINT (21.8485186954945 64.2827396827278)
    
    OGRFeature(SELECT):2
      shp_id (Integer) = 12
      excel_id (Integer) = 12
      attr (String) = baz
      POINT (21.9344382498167 64.4410125459529)
```

Only the three features with the matching ids were selected.

Notice: I split the ogrinfo command on three lines for making it easier to read. If you try that at home keep the command on a single line.